# What's a good app for restoring the functionality removed from Health in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, health

Prior to iOS 10, the Health app made it easy to collect and focus on health aspects  of interest, and to view how these change over time. It was possible to:

- collect (only) specific aspects (weight, steps walked, body fat, etc.) together so on a single page,
- view graphs all of these aspects together over varying time frames (day, week, month, etc.), and
- sort the order in which this information appears.

In iOS 10, all of these features have been removed, and what remains of this functionality is scattered in different places (a page of textual panels that just lists the current day's numbers; a single graph and app advertising page).

What's a good app for restoring the functionality listed above that was removed from Health in iOS 10?